# How to pop from an array inside a hashref?

Tags: arrays, perl, random, hash, hashref

Brain getting foggy on this one.  I wanted to take my dice game from using rand() to using a list of random values from random.org.  I was able to retrieve the values just fine, I'm just hung up on the syntax to pop from the list.

Here's my function that's giving me fits:

```
sub roll_d
{
  return (pop($$dice_stack{@_[0]}));
  # Original code:
  #return (int(rand @_[0]) + 1);
}
```

Where $dice_stack is a pointer to a hash where the key is the dice type ('6' for d6, '20' for d20), and the value is an array of integers between 1 and the dice type.

Comment: It would help if you posted exact error you get AND exact contents of $dice_stack from `Data::Dumper`. It's possible to guess what the heck is under the hood but we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: The warning caused by `@_[0]` can be avoided using the more proper `$_[0]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$$dice_stack{@_[0]}` - aka `$dice_stack->{@_[0]}` - is a VALUE in a hashref. As such, it will necessarily be a scalar and can't be a poppable-from-array.

If the value is an **array reference**, you need to de-reference:

```
  return ( pop(@{ $dice_stack->{ @_[0] } }) );
```

If it's NOT an arrayref, you need to access it in some other way.

Also, this is starting to look golfish - at this point of line noisiness, I would recommend switching to more readable code (IMHO):

```
  my ($dice_type) = @_;
  my $dice_list = $dice_stack->{$dice_type};
  return pop(@$dice_list);
```

Comment: Aha, you are correct, sir.  Left out that part on my description (and in my code, apparently). Thank you.

Comment: Just a note: Starting with Perl 5.14, "pop" can take a scalar EXPR, which must hold a reference to an unblessed array.  The argument will be dereferenced automatically.  This aspect of "pop" is considered highly experimental.  The exact behaviour may change in a future version of Perl.

Comment: @Joel: I’m rather unfond of that “feature”, as it doesn’t autovivify with push the way it should.

Comment: @Joel: `push $cities{$state}, $city;` won’t autoviv. You still have to use `push @{ $cities{$state} }, $city;` the first time. It’s dumb.

Comment: @tchrist, ok so `push` is a little screwy (do you think that this will be addressed in the future?), still `pop` should be ok don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Try dereferencing the array first:

```
pop(@{$dice_stack{@_[0]}})
```